# Python Filling Forward by Section

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         group_a     group_b        group_c     group_d     
0    maintenance          65          green       steve
1    maintenance                      blue        Sally
2    maintenance                      pink        Jay
3       helpdesk                      green       Ian
4             hr          32          green       Tyler
```

What I want to return, is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         group_a     group_b        group_c     group_d     
0    maintenance          65          green       steve
1    maintenance          65           blue        Sally
2    maintenance          65           pink        Jay
3       helpdesk                      green       Ian
4             hr          32          green       Tyler
```

I want to be able to fill forward, but I want to do it by group_a.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace empty string to missing values and then forward filling values per groups:

```
df['group_b'] = df['group_b'].replace('', np.nan)
df['group_b'] = df.groupby('group_a')['group_b'].ffill()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Mask `df.group_a`, using the `loc` accessor. replace the empty space with `NaN` then `ffill` the mask

```
df.loc[df.group_a.eq('maintenance'),'group_b']=df.loc[df.group_a.eq('maintenance'),'group_b'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()
 
     group_a   group_b group_c group_d
0  maintenance      65   green   steve
1  maintenance      65    blue   Sally
2  maintenance      65    pink     Jay
3     helpdesk           green     Ian
4           hr      32   green   Tyler
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pandas function fillna() can take a Series mapping each index to the value that should be used to fill the missing value.

So we need to gather a Series mapping :

```
df = df.set_index("group_a")  # in case it wasn't already the index
df = df.replace("", np.nan)  # in case your missing values are empty strings instead of actual NaNs

mapping = df["group_b"].dropna().drop_duplicates()
```

Now we can:

```
df["group_b"].fillna(mapping, inplace=True)
df
```